# Get error (Illegal query expression: must be surrounded with curly brackets) while trying to fetch details about test-set in QC ALM Rest api

Tags: java, hp-alm, rest-api

I want to update the test results of Cucumber test scenarios to QC ALM using Rest API. I have individual test-set for all automation test scenario (There is a 1-1 mapping between automation test scenario name and test-set name). So to get the test-set id for particular automation scenario, I am calling the rest API through Java.

```
http://xxxx/qcbin/rest/domains//projects//test-set-folders?query={name['Test']}
```

while executing this above with get method, I am getting the below error:

> qccore.general-errorIllegal query expression: must be surrounded with curly brackets

The GET method works fine, if I have query like this:

```
?query={id[123]}
```

The ALM version is 11.52.536. Please help to solve this.

Comment: Try to amend singlequotes to doublequotes in your query.

Comment: I believe the real case is not about "Test" name, there should be either whitespaces or some special characters vreaking the query grammar

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried that already (with single quote, double quote and without any quote.  But every time getting the same error.

Comment: What is the exact value you're passing to the failing query?

Comment: http://es-xxxx/qcbin/rest/domains/xxx/projects/ContentCreationPlatform/test-set-folders?query={name["Sprint 2"]}

Comment: the response is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><QCRestException><Id>qccore.general-error</Id><Title>Illegal query expression: must be surrounded with curly brackets</Title><ExceptionProperties/></QCRestException>

Comment: Try {name[="Sprint 2"]}

Comment: same error  http://es-alm.mhf.mhc/qcbin/rest/domains/Platts/projects/ContentCreationPlatform/test-set-folders?query={name[="Sprint 2"]}
Response code in run folder : 500
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><QCRestException><Id>qccore.general-error</Id><Title>Illegal query expression: must be surrounded with curly brackets</Title><ExceptionProperties/></QCRestException>

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late, but if anybody needs this, the problem is with the URL encoding, use %20 instead of white spaces.

For example with "Sprint 2" the URL would be:
http://xxxx/qcbin/rest/domains//projects//test-set-folders?query={name["Sprint%202"]}
This also affects other special characters, like # (which is %23)

I use this page to verify those simbols:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp